# Need help or suggestions with C# script for Unity2D Android, regarding adverts. Unity suggests my code is obsolete

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

This is the code "template" I used for adverts in my project. Although the adverts are working (A bit slow when testing). Unity gives me this: "ShowOptions.resultCallback' is obsolete: 'Implement `IUnityAdsListener` and call `Advertisement.AddListener()`. I tried to do adverts by using a listener, but it failed to work... Any suggestions?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    string gameId;
    bool testMode;
    string placementId;

    void Start()
    {
        gameId = "<my id here>";
        testMode = false;
        placementId = "<placement id here>";
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, true);
    }

    void ShowAd()
    {
        if (Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
        {
            //Give internet connectivity feedback here
        }
        else
        {
            ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions();
            options.resultCallback = HandleShowResult;
            Advertisement.Show(placementId, options);
        }
    }

    void HandleShowResult(ShowResult result)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
            case ShowResult.Finished:
               //Advert completed
            break;

            case ShowResult.Skipped:
               //Advert skipped
            break;

            case ShowResult.Failed:
               //Advert failed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Image:The error I get when using the listener method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1SJK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error basically tells you exactly what to do:

> ShowOptions.resultCallback' is obsolete: 'Implement IUnityAdsListener and call Advertisement.AddListener()'

In the [API](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity) there is a complete example! Adopted to your code:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{
    private string gameId;
    private bool testMode;
    private string placementId;

    private bool adsAreReady;

    private void Start()
    {
        gameId = "<my id here>";
        testMode = false;
        placementId = "<placement id here>";

        // WAIT FOR ADS
        Advertisment.AddListener(this);

        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, true);
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
        {
            //Give internet connectivity feedback here

            return;
        }

        if(!adsAreReady)
        {
            // Give not ready yet feedback

            return;
        }

        ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions();
        Advertisement.Show(placementId, options);
    }

    // Implement IUnityAdsListener interface methods:
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish (string placementId, ShowResult showResult) 
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        switch(showResult)
        {
            case ShowResult.Finished:
                // Reward the user for watching the ad to completion.
                break;

            case ShowResult.Skipped:
                // Do not reward the user for skipping the ad.
                break;

            case ShowResult.Failed:
                Debug.LogWarning (“The ad did not finish due to an error.);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady (string placementId) 
    {
        if (placementId != myPlacementId) return;

        adsAreReady = true;
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError (string message) 
    {
        // Log the error.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart (string placementId) 
    {
        // Optional actions to take when the end-users triggers an ad.
    } 
}
```

**NOTE** that in your code you never call `ShowAdd` .. it should probably be `public` and called from somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did try implementing the API suggestion into my code, but it's all new for me (It didn't show any ads)... I can see out of your solution that I might have interpreted it a bit wrong. Thank you kindly.

Comment: This part: " Advertisment.AddListener(this);". Returns an error: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NewAdvertsTest' to 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.IUnityAdsListener'" Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe the `IUnityAdsListener` implementation for that class? Should be `public class NewAdvertsTest : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener`